# jQuery - index() function returns wrong index (CheckBox and Select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I've created list of **CheckBox** elements and **Select** with same values as previously mentioned list. What I achieve to do is if I change **CheckBox** selection, **Select list** automaticly updates itself to the same named option as **CheckBox**. I've created this in pure **JavaScript** (and it's working) like this:

```
function addChckBoxListener() {
    for (var i = 0; i < chckBox.length; i++) {
        (function(index) {
            chckBox[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
                update(0, index);
            });
        })(i);   
    }    
}

function addSelectListListener() {
    selectList.addEventListener("change", function() {
        update(1, this.selectedIndex); 
    });
}
```

Later, I wanted to achieve the same with **jQuery** library but it's **index()** function returns wrong index. I have no idea why. Here is same code but in jQuery:

```
function addChckBoxListener() {
    chckBox.each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            update(0, $(this).index());    
        });
    });   
}
function addSelectListListener() {
    selectList.change(function() {
        update(1, $(this).selectedIndex);  
    });
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="red">&nbsp;Czerwony</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="blue" checked>&nbsp;Niebieski</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="green">&nbsp;Zielony</li> 
        </ul>
        <select name="selectColors">
            <option value="red">Czerwony</option>
            <option value="blue" selected="selected">Niebieski</option>
            <option value="green">Zielony</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

In case you want to test this code, here is the link (JSFiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/8yayr972/1/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with the usage of [**index**](https://api.jquery.com/index/).The checkbox is always the first element inside the `li`.So no matter what it' index will be 0. The index of the `li` seems to be useful.So inside this function,instead of querying index of the checkbox,query for the index of it's parent that is `li`

```
function addChckBoxListener() {
  chckBox.each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
     update(0, $(this).parent().index()); // changed here
    });
  });
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8yayr972/2/)

Comment: Looks like CheckBox selection works fine with parent() function. Do you have idea why selectedIndex in Select list change listener is not working? I've read there is new prop("attr") function but is it necessary to use it? Thanks for answer.